# Why twitter.showUser(12).getLang() return null currently whoever the user id, event that it worked perfect in the past

Tags: java, twitter4j

twitter.showUser(12).getLang() return null always
even that it worked well in the past

twitter4j

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
            .setOAuthConsumerKey("")
            .setOAuthConsumerSecret("")
            .setOAuthAccessToken("")
            .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("")
            .setTweetModeExtended(true);
    cb.setJSONStoreEnabled(true);

    TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
    Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();
    System.out.println(twitter.showUser(12).getLang());
```

I expect to return the profile lang for the user
but it returns always null

Comment: May be the user remove it (profile language, I don't know if it's possible)

Comment: No, cause I put my account id, and the result is also null!

Comment: and twitter.showUser(12) give you what you want?

Comment: No, it returns null whoever the id is!

Comment: so check your account id, and put it as a long (12l with a L)

Comment: I tried it, and the result is null also.

Comment: Your accessToken and consumer are correct?

Comment: Yes of course and all twitter4j work correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lang has been removed from the user object. You can see the announcement [here](https://twittercommunity.com/t/upcoming-changes-to-user-object-and-get-users-suggestions-endpoints/124732) .